# How in MSVS C++, work on multiple projects of different solutions?

Tags: projects-and-solutions, multiple-projects

I created two projects in different **Solutions**. Project1 **Calculator** which is *Static Lib(.lib)* containing multiple functions and Project2 **Trigger** which is *Application Exe(.exe)* is try to use the functions of **Calculator**.
How can I do this in Microsoft Visual Studio.

1. I tried to Link the path of Calculator.lib in **Trigger >> Linker >> General >> Addition Libraries Directories** and **Trigger >> Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies**. But It did not work.
   It is giving **Error :**
   Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl opt::add<int,int>(int,int)" (??$add@HH@opt@@YANHH@Z) referenced in function _main D:\Projects\CppCon\Trigger\Trigger\Master.obj   Trigger
   Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\Projects\CppCon\Trigger\Debug\Trigger.exe    1   Trigger 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1. Add a new solution folder and clone the solution and use it.
Way 2. Get the correct path and paste in the C/C++ > General and build it.